# Laravel scope query must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel, model

I am using scope queries within Laravel's Models to assign custom query functions. This particular function has been giving me issues telling me I must supply the parameter as an array, and not a String.

```
/**
 * Get all labs of a class
 * TODO: Fix error
 * @param $query
 * @param $subjectCode Course subject code i.e. "PHYS"
 * @param $courseNo    Course # i.e. "101" or "%" for everything
 * @return mixed       A list of lectures of the class
 */
public function scopeLabsByClass($query, $subjectCode, $courseNo) {
    return $query
        ->where('subject_code', 'like', $subjectCode)
        ->where('course_no', 'like', $courseNo)
        ->whereIn('instr_type', 'like', LAB)
        ;
}
```

When I run it using Tinker:

```
>>> App\SchoolClass::LabsByClass('ece', '201')->get();
```

I get the following error.

> PHP error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php
>   on line 311 and defined in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php
>   on line 113

The code I have is similar to the tutorial from [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/lessons/global-query-scopes) where the first input to the scope method is the `$query`

Comment: Your call to `whereIn()` looks wrong. It takes a column name and an array of values.

Comment: Oh my God you are right. I was playing around with arrays in `whereIn`, and decided against doing that. Forgot to change it back to `where`. I am so silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with the `whereIn` function but forgot to remove it when I went back to my original solution.

```
/**
 * Get all labs of a class
 * TODO: Fix error
 * @param $query
 * @param $subjectCode Course subject code i.e. "PHYS"
 * @param $courseNo    Course # i.e. "101" or "%" for everything
 * @return mixed       A list of lectures of the class
 */
public function scopeLabsByClass($query, $subjectCode, $courseNo) {
    return $query
        ->where('subject_code', 'like', $subjectCode)
        ->where('course_no', 'like', $courseNo)
        ->where('instr_type', 'like', LAB)
        // LAB is a String constant defined on the top of the doc
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the L in Labs to lowercase.

```
App\SchoolClass::labsByClass('ece', '201')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, it's a constant `define('LAB', 'Lab');`

Comment: Try this, I don't think it will matter. `App\SchoolClass::labsByClass(['ece', '201'])->get();` Your code looks OK.